# Apportable trivial conversion errors

Tags: apportable

I'm encountering errors while cross-compiling using **Apportable** which ends with **"scons: building terminated because of errors."**

When I say apportable load, it goes into the compilation step and then spits out 21 errors (and a few warnings). I think there may already be a way to debug most of them, but I do not know how to tackle them because I am new to apportable.

Here is an example of 3 of the 21 errors. **What can I do to get this to work?**

Thanks for the help!

1. **error:** no visible @interface for
     'NSDateComponents' declares the selector 'setTimeZone:'
    [dc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:(NSString *)serverTimeZoneName]];
    ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
2. **error:** use of undeclared identifier 'NSFontAttributeName'
   CGSize textSize = [self.activityLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
   [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]}];  ~~~~~ ^~~~~
3. **error:** no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'endUpdates'
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
   ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do when you are trying to get your app working the first time using Apportable is to disable the lines of code that aren't compiling.  For example:

```
#if !defined(ANDROID)
[dc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:(NSString *)serverTimeZoneName]];
#endif
```

Once you have it compiling, linking, and running, it is much easier to determine the best way to deal with the differences between Apportable and iOS.